# Is it possible to automatically obtain abstracts and citations from a list of references?

Tags: literature-search, bibliometrics, reference-managers

I have a list of about 150 references stored in my reference manager. They are from my dissertation. My end goal is to do a bibliometric analysis of these papers to visualize their network of connections based on the overlap of articles cited within each paper (and alternatively based on shared terms in the abstracts). Typically I do network analysis on papers returned from searches using the Web of Science, which generates a file containing the abstracts and lists of references for all of the papers I am analyzing. There appears to be no way to compile sets of papers using WoS other than to do a search though. This means I would have to individually search for all ~150 of my dissertation references and add them to my marked list. That is impractical. Are there any citation databases into which I can import a reference list and automatically compile a set of abstracts/references-cited for each reference?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but from the little I know about bibliometrics, matching references is very difficult. So, it might not be as easy as you think to just feed in a list of references from one source (your reference manager) and automatically match them from a database (e.g. WoS).

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: Which citation analysis software do you use? A possible answer might be available for specific software. Please edit your question to specify. You can also specify your specific reference manager.

Comment: If a solution exists, I would probably start from the scholarly database (e.g. WoS) and see if they have any instructions for importing a list of references (maybe using DOIs) whose full details they would then display. If there is no import option from the database end, then there is likely no solution for that particular database.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of DOI's and a scopus/web of science login (via your institution) they have API's available to automatically obtain this data. For example, using python, you could use the packages [pybliometrics](https://pypi.org/project/pybliometrics/) or [wos](https://pypi.org/project/wos/) to go through this list.